# Running asynchronous code synchronously in separate thread

Tags: django, python-asyncio, django-channels

I'm using Django Channels to support websockets and am using their concept of a group to broadcast messages to multiple consumers in the same group. In order to send messages outside of a consumer, you need to call asynchronuous methods in otherwise synchronous code. Unfortunately, this is presenting problems when testing.

I began by using `loop.run_until_complete`:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(channel_layer.group_send(group_name, {'text': json.dumps(message),
                                                                                    'type': 'receive_group_json'}),
                                              loop=loop))
```

Then the stacktrace read that the thread did not have an event loop: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.`. To solve this, I added:

```
loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.ensure_future(channel_layer.group_send(group_name, {'text': json.dumps(message),
                                                                                    'type': 'receive_group_json'}),
                                              loop=loop))
```

And now the stacktrace is reading the `RuntimeError: Event loop is closed`, although if I add print statements `loop.is_closed()` prints `False`.

For context, I'm using Django 2.0, Channels 2, and a redis backend.

**Update**: I tried running this in a Python interpreter (outside of py.test to remove moving variables). When I ran the second code block, I did not get an `Event loop is closed` error (that may be due to something on Pytest's end whether its timeouts, etc). But, I did not receive the group message in my client. I did, however, see a print statement:

```
({<Task finished coro=<RedisChannelLayer.group_send() done, defined at /Users/my/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py:306> result=None>}, set())
```

**Update 2**: After flushing redis, I added a fixture in py.test to flush it for every function as well as a session-scoped event loop. This time yielding yet another print from RedisChannelLayer:

```
({<Task finished coro=<RedisChannelLayer.group_send() done, defined at /Users/my/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py:306> exception=RuntimeError('Task <Task pending coro=<RedisChannelLayer.group_send() running at /Users/my/path/to/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/channels_redis/core.py:316>> got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop',)>}, set())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `channel_layer` expects to reside in its own event loop in another thread, you will need to get a hold of that event loop object. Once you have it, you can submit coroutines to it and synchronize with your thread, like this:

```
def wait_for_coro(coro, loop):
    # submit coroutine to the event loop in the other thread
    # and wait for it to complete
    future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)
    return future.wait()

wait_for_coro(channel_layer.group_send(group_name, ...), channel_loop)
```

Comment: What's the standard practice for passing the event loop between threads? Do I need to pass the event loop as an argument into the worker thread? Or is there a call in the daphne or async lib?

Comment: @williamrfry Since the event loop is an object like any other, passing `asyncio.get_event_loop()` an argument to the worker thread is perfectly fine. The only thing to remember is that you're not allowed to *do* anything with that event loop in the worker thread (e.g. submit tasks or query its state), except through `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, only the main thread gets an event loop and calling `get_event_loop` in other threads will fail.

If you need an event loop in another thread -- such as a thread handling an HTTP or WebSockets request -- you need to make it yourself with `new_event_loop`. After that you can use `set_event_loop` and future `get_event_loop` calls will work. I do this:

```
# get or create an event loop for the current thread
def get_thread_event_loop():
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # gets previously set event loop, if possible
    except RuntimeError:
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    return loop
```

[More here](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2016/10/30/i-dont-understand-asyncio/).